# How to make CalendarExtender show in front of ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: asp.net

How to make CalendarExtender, extending TextBox placed inside ModalPopupExtender, to show in front of ModalPopupExtender ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this bit of javascript to your page:

```
    function calendarShown(sender, args)
    {
        sender._popupBehavior._element.style.zIndex = 10005;
    }
```

And then in the attributes for your calendar extender, add:

```
OnClientShown="calendarShown"
```

Comment: worked for me, but had to change zIndex from 10005 to 99999999 or else the calendar still popped up below the dialog.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me by as well as ptutt comments

Answer (score 2):

My solution is in CSS:

```
.ajax__calendar_container
{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is not as arbitrary as setting a very high zIndex and works via CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Ajax library resolved this issue as well

Comment: This should be comment not answer.